# Bad receiver type 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *')

Tags: objective-c

Here is my method `createNewRectangleWithHeight` and the parameter is heightParam and widthParam. My problem is i can't use the parameter in the method.

I am getting an error something like this

**Bad receiver type 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *')**

```
-(BOOL)createNewRectangleWithHeight:(NSUInteger *)heightParam width:(NSUInteger *)widthParam{

    if ([[heightParam length] == 0] || [widthParam length]==0]) {
        NSLog(@"The height and width must no be 0");
    }
}
```

Error is in if condition

Answer (score 2):

You can only call methods on objects.  A pointer to an `unsigned int` is not an object; it's just the address of a number.

You don't need to pass addresses unless you're changing the value inside your method and you can just check the value rather than treating the number as an object.

```
-(BOOL)createNewRectangleWithHeight:(NSUInteger)heightParam width:(NSUInteger)widthParam {

    if (heightParam == 0 || widthParam == 0) {
        NSLog(@"The height and width must not be 0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn to look at the error messages you get. In this case the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. The syntax `[object message]` is sending a message to an object. NSInteger is a scalar type, not an object type.

BTW, your method does not return a result, and is badly named. It should be called something like heightAndWidthAreNotZero.

Others have already pointed out that you should be using `(NSUInteger)`, not `(NSUInteger *)`, as your parameter types. Actually, if you're getting ready to create a CGRect, you should probably be using CGFloat, not NSUInteger, since the different values of a CGRect are CGFloat type.

Finally, there is a built-in system function CGRectIsEmpty() that takes a CGRect as input and returns TRUE if the rectangle is empty, and FALSE if it's not empty.